# Machine learning in Python: scikit-learn / Pybrain

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, pybrain

I read some tutorials and introductions but I'm not sure I'm getting the hang of it and, most of all, I'm not sure I understand ML vs NN completely.

Suppose that I want to instruct a program (like with scikit-learn) so that it has some language dictionary as its input set. For example, I have a large dictionary of Italian words that I can input as an array of arrays (each item of the array being a single word and each word is an array of ascii values, one for each character of the world):

```
[
    [112, 105, 122, 122, 97], // pizza
    [109, 097, 109, 109, 97], // mamma
    ...
]
```

Is it possibile / what is the best library / how to do this:

1. Given a word, have the program infer if it could be an Italian word, so that "mafia" is recognized as a potential actual Italian word but "Eichhörnchen" is not (it is longer than the average Italian world, it contains sequences like "rnch" that are not found in the initial set, it contains "ö" that is a character not used in Italian)
2. Generate other (likely) Italian words based on the initial set. For example, "potomo" is not an actual Italian word but, according to Italian orthography it *could* be

Answer (score 0):

I think Naive Bayesian classification and KNN can be used.Naive Bayesian classification was proved can Filter spam，but you need a Thesaurus before this.